# Соединить две/три таблицы, сохраняя все записи всех таблиц

Tags: mysql

На данный момент у меня есть две таблицы (третья добавиться позже).

Первая таблица под названием titles_quizes включает в себя все существуещие экзамены в базе данных:

| Title_QuizID | Title | SubjectID | Draft |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Basic | 104 | 0 |
| 35 | Prof | 104 | 0 |
| 37 | 123123 | 89 | 1 |
| 38 | 123123123 | 104 | 0 |

Вторая таблица под названием savged_quizes включает в себя экзамены которые сохранил для себя пользователь:

| savedQuizID | Title_QuizID | UserID | Title_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 | 19 | 123123123 |
| 2 | 35 | 19 | Prof |

На странице экзаменов (например все экзамены у которых SubjectID=104) я хочу вывести все экзамены и выделить те что сохранены у данного юзера.

Например:

| Title_QuizID | Title | SubjectID | Draft | savedQuizID | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Basic | 104 | 0 | null | null |
| 35 | Prof | 104 | 0 | 2 | 19 |
| 37 | 123123 | 89 | 1 | null | null |
| 38 | 123123123 | 104 | 0 | 1 | 19 |

Есть ли возможность создать такую таблицу или соединить две таблицы в одну.

На данный момент я попробовала использовать следующий запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM titles_quizes LEFT JOIN savged_quizes ON titles_quizes.Title_QuizID = savged_quizes.Title_QuizID
```

Данный запрос возвращает мне следущую таблицу:

| Title_QuizID | Title | SubjectID | Draft | savedQuizID | Title_QuizID | UserID | Title_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | Basic | 104 | 0 | null | null | null | null |
| 35 | Prof | 104 | 0 | 2 | 35 | 19 | Prof |
| 37 | 123123 | 89 | 1 | null | null | null | null |
| 38 | 123123123 | 104 | 0 | 1 | 38 | 19 | 123123123 |

Запрос

```
SELECT 
titles_quizes.Title_QuizID,
titles_quizes.Title,
titles_quizes.SubjectID,
titles_quizes.Draft,
savged_quizes.savedQuizID,
savged_quizes.UserID
FROM titles_quizes LEFT JOIN savged_quizes ON titles_quizes.Title_QuizID = savged_quizes.Title_QuizID
```

Дает мне нужную мне таблицу с нужными мне даннами, но я хотела узнать как можно улучшить запрос.
В случае есть мне нужно будет добавить или убрать другие столбцы, мне кажеться перечеслять их всех будет очень муторно и может создавать проблемы.

Comment: _перечеслять их всех будет очень муторно_ - это правильный подход, так и надо делать.

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько вариантов синтаксиса связывания.

Вы хотите, чтобы не было дублирования полей, используемых для связи? Тогда используйте либо JOIN .. USING, либо NATURAL JOIN.

В случае NATURAL JOIN таблицы связываются по всем одноимённым полям. В случае JOIN .. USING - только по тем, которые указываются. В обоих случаях поля связывания включаются в выходной набор только один раз. В случае внешнего связывания (LEFT JOIN) значения берутся из левой таблицы (для RIGHT JOIN - соответственно из правой).

Поля связывания помещаются в самое начало выходной структуры. Если обращаться к полям по имени, это не составляет проблемы.

То есть Вы можете использовать запрос

```
SELECT * 
FROM titles_quizes 
LEFT JOIN savged_quizes USING (Title_QuizID)
```

---

Впрочем, я полностью согласен с комментарием

> *перечеслять их всех будет очень муторно* - это правильный подход, так и надо делать. – [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov)

Небольшое облегчение на стадии разработки может аукнуться большими проблемами в будущем.

PS. Я вообще считаю, что звезда вместо списка полей должна использоваться только в COUNT(*).

Comment: Что в имеете в виду "Небольшое облегчение на стадии разработки"?

Comment: @KatyaRu Ну Вы же хотите избавить себя от рутинной работы по перечислению полей в списке вывода...

Comment: Конечно, в особености в случае когда в будущем добавяться еще поля с третей таблицы. То что я бы еще хотела, это убирать не только поля которые повторяются но еще поля которыми я не пользуюсь. например savged_quizes.Title_Name

Comment: @KatyaRu Ну лень это, обычная лень.. которая запросто может больно аукнуться в будущем. Лучше даже не привыкайте.